# c++ vector.push_back error: request for member 'push_back'..., which is of non-class type 'vector(char, allocator(char)) ()()'

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, cygwin, compilation

I'm using Cygwin with GCC, and ultimately I want to read in a file of characters into a vector of characters, and using this code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    vector<char> string1();
    string1.push_back('a');

    return 0;
}
```

generates this compile time error:

> main.cpp: In function `int main(int,
>   char**)': main.cpp:46: error: request
>   for member`push_back' in `string1',
>   which is of non
>   -class type`std::vector > ()()'

I tried this with a vector of ints and strings as well and they had the same problem.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Don't use parentheses to invoke the default constructor:

```
vector<char> string1;
```

Otherwise this declares a function `string1` that takes no argumentes and returns a `vector<char>`.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the parens in the declaration of the `vector` - they cause it to be a function declaration and not a vector declaration.